# Help Needed with a Hook_form_alter Module

Tags: hooks, webforms

I've written the following module and it's not working. By that I mean it's not printing the #prefix to the webform above the 'resource_name' field. In fact, it's not printing it anywhere on the page. I'm trying to alter a webform-created node. I've already verified the form_id is correct as listed. And according to the webform the 'resource_name' is the field key for the field above which I want to place the #prefix markup. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Note also that yes I've enabled the module.

```
    <?php

    function webformalter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      // Check when the right form is passed
      if ($form_id == ' webform_client_form_289') {

        // Add the directions
        $form['resource_name'] = array(
          '#prefix' => '<p>Do you know of a high-quality resource that should be in our 
listings?</p><p>Please let us know! We will review it before publishing it, and we will 
follow up with any questions.</p>',
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your not setting the prefix correctly. I think you want to do something more like this:

```
if ($form_id == ' webform_client_form_289') {
    // Add the directions
    $form['submitted']['#prefix'] = '<p>Do you know of a high-quality resource that should be in our listings?</p><p>Please let us know! We will review it before publishing it, and we will follow up with any questions.</p>';
}
```

Looks like what your trying to do on in your code is set resource_name to be an array with just prefix in it.

Comment: thanks I edited it but it still won't work. 'resource_name' is just a field in the form (there are other fields), fyi. Not sure if that's the problem. When I dpm($form) the resource_name variable is buried under #node > webform > components > resource_name. But when I try adding the prefix with that elongated path it doesn't work either. So now I'm not sure what else to try. Other ideas?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to alter the form that creates the webform, or a component on the form that webform generates for you?

Comment: @Sage, actually, on my test site, the form element is stored at $form['submitted']['resource_name'] (I updated my answer to that). If that is in your $form variable, that's probably where you want to make your changes.

Comment: @Jance cool, yea, thanks that worked. For others, this is the URL that explains how to hook_form_alter webforms specifically: https://www.drupal.org/node/1558246.